# Can ElasticSearch handle 20 million of query a day?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to develop a system based on ElasticSearch which should executes 20 million of query a day. Is ES able to scale properly to handle a such mole of data?

Comment: Did you mean: 20 **billion** queries a day? :-)

Comment: No, I mean 20 million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "yes", there surely are installations of Elasticsearch that handle much much higher load.

However it largely It fully depends on how powerful your Elasticsearch-cluster is and how complex the queries are.

If you convert it into a per-second value you see that you are talking about roughly 230 queries per second.

There are always ways to make it work by simply providing more nodes and more replicas and by ensuring that the query-load is spread out across the different nodes.

So you likely will need to set up a small test-system that has your expected production load of documents and try running queries and then scale it up until it meets your expected performance numbers.